# Using Negative lookbehind with or operator (not preceded by multiple words)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, negative-lookbehind

I've a problem with my regex in Python.

`et`  may only match if it is not preceded by `m` or `mme`

string: `M et Mme Du Pont` or `Mme et M Du Pont`

regex: `'\b(?<!m|mme)\bet\b'`

error: `look-behind requires fixed-with patterd`

How can i fix this?

`'\b(?<!m)(?<!mme)\bet\b'` doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the error, there is a space in the example data after `m` and `mme` which is missing in the pattern.

Another option is to use the [regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with a single lookbehind asserting what is directly at the left is `m`, optionally followed by `me` and followed by a space.

```
\b(?<!m(?:me)? )et\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HdBf6m/1) | [Python using regex module demo](https://tio.run/##ZY49C8JAEET7@xXrVncQ0tiJEkSDWERF22sSXONB7oPLCvrrzxgVBKebN8W88OCrd9OUjA0@MkRq6S5EqJkpOlhARN3IYj6xsphZUgUoYt2g6IdNYgXEUFmC9Q0O3jH4ONYX/TLtUMBPkP6RJUY13EbjWI4O@cW4c9118qOSQZ@97fLtZrc/lqvlqVQqpSc)

For example

```
import regex

pattern = r"\b(?<!m(?:me)? )et\b"
s = ("M et Mme Du Pont or Mme et M Du Pont\n"
            "et\n"
            "met")

print(regex.findall(pattern, s, regex.IGNORECASE))
```

Output

```
['et']
```

Comment: Many thanks. What if I need more optional words? For example M, Mme, Mr, Mrs, Miss

Comment: @JohnDoe You could match all those variants `\b(?<!m(?:me|rs?|iss)? )et\b` https://regex101.com/r/ZGQ7YI/1

Answer (score 2):

You may use 2 negative lookbehind assertions like this:

```
(?<!\bM )(?<!\bMme )\bet\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/czqYRV/1)

A space character after `M` and `Mme` is important because in your input you have a space before `et`.

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\bM )`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have `"M "` string before current position
- `(?<!\bMme )`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have `"Mme "` string before current position
- `\bet\b`: Match complete word `et`